# C nested struct syntax struggle

Tags: c

I have the following code and I haven't worked in C for years and I'm confused by the syntax. How could I initialize two patrons within the `init` function? I assume I need to do some `sizeof`/`malloc` magic but really I'm confused on the syntax.

I believe I can access patron data like this:

```
t->seating[0].first_name
```

However, I cannot get the dang array of seating created. Yes, my `init` function is empty as I've deleted all the crazy code I tried.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct patron {
   char last_name[30];
   char first_name[30];
};

struct theatre_seating {
    struct patron **seating;
};

void init(int elem, struct theatre_seating *t);


int main() {
    struct theatre_seating theatre_seating;

    int elem = 2;


    init(elem, &theatre_seating);

    return 1;
}

void init(int elem, struct theatre_seating *t) {

}
```

Comment: There is one too many star on this line: struct patron **seating;
Your theatre wants to contain an 'array' of patrons, so just a single pointer is sufficient. You would need the two *s to have a 2D array of seating, or other use cases.

Comment: BTW, this is just a tiny snippet of code for a rather large homework assignment. I inherited a **pointer and have to deal with it. It's the ** within the nested struct that I'm having trouble unwrapping. **seating will ultimately be a pointer to a 2-dimensional array holding patrons. I'll be getting the rows and cols at runtime and passing it to init(row, col, theatre_seating *t) and dealing with **seating in the real function. All that aside, I have to implement **seating not *seating

Comment: Then you need to change `t->seating[0].first_name` to `t->seating[0][0].first_name` . Two *s in the declaration match 2 stars (or []) in the usage.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
// First you need to include necessary header files,
// to invoke memory allocation functions,
// such as `malloc`, `calloc`, etc.
#include <stdlib.h>

struct patron {
    // Beware the following declaration leads to inefficient memory usage
    char last_name[30];
    char first_name[30];
};

struct theatre_seating {
    // Keeps a track of how long the following array is
    size_t len_seating;
    // Array pointer
    struct patron * seating;
};

int init(int elem, struct theatre_seating *t);

int main() {
    // Usually people initialize a `struct` with `{ 0 }`
    // to make sure every member in it is empty,
    // and to prevent undefined behaviour
    struct theatre_seating theatre_seating = { 0 };

    int elem = 2;

    if (init(elem, &theatre_seating))
    {
        // TODO
    }

    // ALWAYS remember to destroy
    // dynamically allocated memory
    // at the end of the thread
    free(theatre_seating.seating);

    // Instead of (1), return (0) to indicate successful result.
    return 0;
}

// I don't know what argument `elem` stands for
// but I assume that it stands for the number of seats
// (aka. the length of `seating` array)
//
// @return: 1, upon successful memory allocation
//          0, otherwise
int init(int elem, struct theatre_seating *t) {
    t->len_seating = elem;
    t->seating = calloc(elem, sizeof(struct patron));

    // Remember to check if dynamic allocation is successful
    return (int) t->seating;
}
```

---

## Update:

```
int create_seating(int nRows, int nCols, struct patron ** seating)
{
    int i = 0;

    seating = (struct patron **) calloc(nRows, sizeof(struct patron *));
    if (seating)
    {
        for (; i < nRows; i++)
        {
            seating[i] = (struct patron *) calloc(nCols, sizeof(struct patron));
            if (seating[i])
                continue;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return i;
}

void destroy_seating(int nRows, struct patron ** seating)
{
    int i;

    if (seating)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
        {
            free(seating[i]);
        }

        free(seating);
    }
}
```

Comment: `free(NULL)` is a no-op; you don't need to check the pointer beforehand.

Comment: I recommend avoiding identifiers starting with `_`. A single leading `_` followed by a lowercase letter is technically fine on local variables, but why tempt fate?

Comment: You don't need that `memset` call. Leaving the memory uninitialized doesn't cause undefined behavior. If you do need to set it to 0, `calloc` instead of `malloc` / `memset` would be more efficient. As a side effect, it also prevents integer overflow in `elem * sizeof(struct patron)`.

Comment: Now that you've edited your code, `memset` is gone, so you don't need `#include <string.h>` anymore. Technically you don't need the return value from `init` either because the caller can just check `if (theatre_seating.seating)` directly. :-)

Comment: I'd like to keep memory allocation check inside `init`, bcoz in my mind it should be part of its logic. :P

Comment: KaiserKatze - I have to retain the double pointer **seating. This is a small snippet of code for a quite large homework project. My issue is with **seating within the nested structs. NominalAnimal's reply below appears to clarify how to create/access the array elements while retaining **seating which is to be a pointer to an array of struct patrons. The portion of the real program I have to write which is very loosely represented in this post will be getting the row/col at runtime for which I have to create a two-dimensional array of patrons of that size which **seating will point to.

Comment: It's unnecessary to implement a 2-dimensional array to access rows and columns of a matrix. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51962613/4927212).

Comment: Anyway if you must retain the double pointer `**seating`, then yes, you need to allocate memory for the 2-dimensional array, and check out my update.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach, that should be a bit more robust. It uses C99's flexible array member.

Instead of fixed-size arrays, put the character data to the flexible array member. The first name is stored first, followed by (an end of string NUL, `\0` and) the last name (and an another end of string NUL).

To avoid having to find where the first name starts, we can store either a pointer, or an offset. I prefer the offset, but as long as you (the programmer!) are careful, the pointer will work fine as well:

```
struct patron {
    char *last_name;    /* Points to within the first_name member */
    char  first_name[]; /* Flexible array member */
};
```

Usually, you write helper functions to allocate and initialize, as well as free, such structures:

```
void free_patron(struct patron *p)
{
    if (p) {
        /* "Poisoning" the structure, to help detect possible use-after-free bugs. */
        p->last_name = NULL;
        p->first_name[0] = '\0';

        /* Both names reside in the same dynamically allocated part. */
        free(p);
    }
}

struct patron *new_patron(const char *first, const char *last)
{
    const size_t   firstlen = (first) ? strlen(first) : 0;
    const size_t   lastlen = (last) ? strlen(last) : 0;
    struct patron *newpatron;

    /* Don't allow unnamed patrons. */
    if (firstlen + lastlen < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "new_patron(): NULL or empty name.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Allocate enough memory for the structure. */
    newpatron = malloc(sizeof (struct patron) + firstlen + 1 + lastlen + 1);
    if (!newpatron) {
        fprintf(stderr, "new_patron(): Not enough memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* First name goes first. */
    if (firstlen > 0)
        memcpy(newpatron->first_name, first, firstlen);
    newpatron->first_name[firstlen] = '\0';

    /* Last name follows. */
    newpatron->last_name = newpatron->first_name + firstlen + 1;
    if (lastlen > 0)
        memcpy(newpatron->last_name, last, lastlen);
    newpatron->last_name[lastlen] = '\0';

    return newpatron;
}
```

To manage an array of patrons, this time each entry is a pointer to a struct patron. This means you can choose whether you use a fixed-size array, where you locate a vacant seating by locating a NULL pointer.

```
struct seating {
    size_t           seats;
    struct patron  **seat;
};

#define  NO_VACANCIES  (~(size_t)0)

void free_seating(struct seating *s)
{
    if (s) {
        free(s->seat);
        s->seats = 0;
        s->seat = NULL;
    }
}

void init_seating(struct seating *s, const size_t n)
{
    size_t  i;

    if (!s) {
        fprintf(stderr, "init_seating(): NULL pointer to struct seating.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* No seats wanted at all? */
    if (n < 1) {
        s->seats = 0;
        s->seat  = NULL;
        return;
    }

    s->seat = malloc(n * sizeof s->seat[0]);
    if (!s->seat) {
        fprintf(stderr, "init_seating(): Not enough memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    s->seats = n;

    /* Initialize all seats as vacant. */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        s->seat[i] = NULL;

    /* Done. */
}

/* Find a vacant/unused seating.
   Returns the seat index, or NO_VACANCIES if all taken. */
size_t vacant_seating(struct seating *s)
{
    size_t  i;

    if (!s || s->seats < 1)
        return NO_VACANCIES;

    for (i = 0; i < s->seats; i++)
        if (!s->seat[i])
            return i; /* Seat i is vacant. */

    return NO_VACANCIES;
}

/* Removes a patron from a seating.
   You'll usually want to call
       free_patron(release_seating(&my_threatre, place));
   to free the structure naming the patron as well.
   This is safe to do even if the seat was vacant. */
struct patron *release_seating(struct seating *s, size_t i)
{
    if (s && i < s->seats) {
        struct patron *old_patron = s->seat[i];
        s->seat[i] = NULL;
        return old_patron;
    } else
        return NULL;
}
```

In your program, using these is simple:

```
struct seating  my_theatre;
size_t          place;

/* Small venue with 50 seats. */
init_seating(&my_theatre, 50);

/* Find a vacant seat. */
place = vacant_seating(&my_theatre);
if (place == NO_VACANCIES) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Sorry, the theatre is full.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

/* Seat DanielN there. */
my_theatre.seat[place] = new_patron("Daniel", "N");
```

Note that because `my_theatre.seat` is an array, `my_theatre.seat + place` is a pointer to the `place`th element in the array, exactly like `&(my_theatre.seat[place])`.

Also note that when allocating arrays, say `struct something *foo;`, you can use the sizeof operator: `foo = malloc(n * sizeof foo[0]);` tries to allocate enough memory for `n` elements of whatever type `foo[0]` is. Note that to help us programmers remember that `sizeof` is an operator, and not a function. Even when `foo` is undefined or NULL, `sizeof foo[0]` is valid, because the sizeof operator only examines the *type* of its argument to determine the size of the type.

The `NO_VACANCIES` macro evaluates to the largest `size_t` value (that the type can describe in binary on non-binary computers). That expression works for all unsigned integer types, and `size_t` is an unsigned (nonnegative) integer type.  It would be better to include `<limits.h>` and use the `SIZE_MAX` (similar to `CHAR_MAX`, `UCHAR_MAX`, `INT_MAX`, and so on that that header file defines), but I'm not sure if all (well, Microsoft; they like to do things their own way) define `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: I was going to ultilize **Flexible array member**, but I didn't know its compiler support.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate C99 compiler support, please?

Comment: @KaiserKatze: All current C compilers should support flexible array members (and all of the code in my example). I suspect only Borland C and perhaps very old versions of Microsoft C (before 2013) might not support those; I definitely expect anything that claims to be a C compiler to support flexible array members. After all, 1999 was 19 years ago, so assuming C99 or later support is reasonable.

Comment: My issue was with the double pointer **seating and how to create/access the seating elements. Nominal Animal clarified the syntax in the "Note that because my_theatre.seat is an array..." This being a homework thing, I actually have to create helper functions based upon provided function prototypes so I will not be stealing your code. I thought I'd get a simple response of here's how'd you'd create a couple patrons inside the init() function and I'd extrapolate the rest into proper code. There's obviously a few different ways to tackle this given the responses, but **seating is required.